# strong maximum principle for parabolic equations

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Here's the proof of the strong maximum principle in Evans book, page 376. It says that let $v$ solves
\begin{align}v_t+Lv&=0 \quad \text{in} \, W_T, \\ v&=u \quad \text{on} \, \Delta_T.\end{align}
Since the proof uses the weak maximum principle later, my question is how can we prove that such $v$ exists and belongs to $C_1^2(U_T)\cap C(\bar{U}_T)$ ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: They are assuming coefficients of $L$ and $u$ are smooth. So you can apply, existence and uniqueness theorems (apply theorem-7) to argue that $v\in C_1^2(W_T)\cap C(\overline{W_T}).$